# JHipster: Upgrade Spring Boot to 2.3.2 from 2.1.8 JHipster Still uses 2.1.8

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I tried changing JHipster  Spring boot app from 2.1.8 to 2.3.2 and it still uses the old version 2.1.8. How do I upgrade to 2.3.2?

Answer (score 2):

JHipster does not support 2.3.x yet, therefore an automatic upgrade is not possible. You can try a manual upgrade by removing the jhipster dependencies bom, such that the boot parent defines all versions and update the boot version to 2.3.2. Keep in mind to read all migration guides for boot 2.1.x -> 2.2.x -> 2.3.x.

Depending on your configuration and used dependencies this might be different.

Comment: Whats involved in just removing jh entirely. I am just running one service in it and dont really need all the bells and whistles for that

Comment: Its just one micro service that I derived from a monolith where I did need jh

Comment: Or is there anyway for me to use Spring Kafka 2.5 with Spring Boot 2.1.8?

Comment: The problem is I need to use Dynamic Type check in Spring Kafka 2.5 and how I am stuck in Spring Boot 2.1.8 which seems to use wrong version of Spring Framework and always pulls in older version of Spring Kafka too

Comment: If you remove the jhipster dependencies you are not bound not any versions enforced/managed by jhipster, which removes jh completly. So you can upgrade boot to 2.3.x but you should be careful as this might break something, so you should read the offical boot migration guides carefully. Most likely there won't be much trouble.

Comment: It broke just about everything @atomfrede

Comment: why no support for 2.3 we are at 2.4 almost now?

Comment: We are working on it, but we depend on more than just jpa for example and some projects are not yet there to have 2.3 support. You can follow along https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/11681. What do you mean it broke everything? What did you do exactly? You still need the jhopster lib, but you can remove the jhipster dependencies bom (which bounds you to 2.1 in your case). But I am not sure how difficult it is. Just know it usually works.